# Html form with complex ASP.NET Core Model

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a complex model that I want to fill and send it to the controller to store it. The problem is that since the model is recursive, I cannot do it, does anyone know a way to do it.

Here is the model class:

```
public class TowerMeasureModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tower { get; set; }
    public DateTime LaunchDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public SetupModel Setup { get; set; }
    public TVList selectionDetails { get; set; }
    public int LaunchType { get; set; }
    public int Calib_Standard { get; set; }
    public int Calib_Band { get; set; }
    public int Calib_Setup { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public static readonly int MEASUREMENT = 0;
    public static readonly int CALIBRATION = 1;
    public static readonly int CALIB_ISDB = 10;
    public static readonly int CALIB_DVB = 11;
    public static readonly int CALIB_TER = 12;
    public static readonly int CALIB_SAT = 13;
    public static readonly int CALIB_SETUP_OPT1 = 14;
    public static readonly int CALIB_SETUP_OPT2 = 15;
    public static readonly int CALIB_SETUP_OPT3 = 16;
    public static readonly int CALIB_SETUP_OPT4 = 17;
    public static readonly int STATUS_WAITING = 20;
    public static readonly int STATUS_STARTED = 21;
    public static readonly int STATUS_PAUSED = 22;
    public static readonly int STATUS_ABORTED = 23;
    public static readonly int STATUS_FINISHED = 24;
}
```

Where the `TVList` parameter is a list of the following items:

```
public abstract class TVItem
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TVItem Parent { get; set; }
    public List<TVItem> Children { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
}
```

As you can observe, the parents are recursive, and this causes the issue to the form.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" id="pageForm" action="/Launch/Home/retrieveSelection">

    <aside>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="Calibration" name="LaunchType" value=1 />
            <label for="Calibration">Calibration</label>
            <hr />
            <input type="radio" id="Measurement" name="LaunchType" value=0 checked="checked"/>
            <label for="Measurement">Measurement</label>
            <hr />
            <label for="LaunchName">Name this run:</label> 
            <input type="text" id="LaunchName" name="LaunchName" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ","_").Replace("/","").Replace(":","")" />
            <hr />
        </div>
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="LaunchArea" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Load">Load</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="LaunchArea" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save">Save</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="LaunchArea" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Reset">Reset</a>
        <input type="submit" class="myULclass" id="myButton" value="Send Run"/>
    </aside>

    <article>

        <h2>Measurements</h2>

        <div style="height:450px ; overflow-y:scroll">
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="1234" />
            <ul>
                @{
                    foreach (TVStandard tvstandard in Model.selectionDetails.StandardsList) {
                        int index = Model.selectionDetails.StandardsList.IndexOf(tvstandard);
                        <li>
                            <input type="hidden" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].folderName" value="@tvstandard.folderName" />
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvstandard.Name" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].IsSelected" value="true">
                            <label for="@tvstandard.Name">@tvstandard.Name</label>
                            <ul class="nested">
                                @{
                                    foreach (TVSection tvsection in tvstandard.Children) {
                                        int index2 = tvstandard.Children.IndexOf(tvsection);
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].scriptName" value="@tvsection.scriptName" />
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvsection.Name" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].IsSelected" value="true">
                                            <label for="@tvsection.Name">@tvsection.Name</label>
                                            <ul class="nested">
                                                @{
                                                    foreach (TVMode tvmode in tvsection.Children) {
                                                        int index3 = tvsection.Children.IndexOf(tvmode);
                                                        <li>
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].Children[@index3].Name" value="@tvmode.Name" />
                                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvmode.Name" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].Children[@index3].IsSelected" value="true">
                                                            <label for="@tvmode.Name">@tvmode.Name</label>
                                                            <ul class="nested">
                                                                @{
                                                                    foreach (TVFreq tvfreq in tvmode.Children) {
                                                                        int index4 = tvmode.Children.IndexOf(tvfreq);
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <input type="hidden" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].Children[@index3].Children[@index4].ID" value="@tvfreq.ID" />
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="@tvfreq.Name" name="selectionDetails.StandardsList[@index].Children[@index2].Children[@index3].Children[@index4].IsSelected" value="true">
                                                                            <label for="@tvfreq.Name">@tvfreq.Name</label>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <h2>Calibration</h2>

        <select style="font-size:medium" form="pageForm" name="Calib_Standard">
            <option value=10>ISDB</option>
            <option value=11>DVB</option>
        </select>
        <select style="font-size:medium" form="pageForm" name="Calib_Band">
            <option value=12>Terrestrial</option>
            <option value=13>Satellite</option>
        </select>
        <select style="font-size:medium" form="pageForm" name="Calib_Setup">
            <option value=14>Option 1</option>
            <option value=15>Option 2</option>
            <option value=16>Option 3</option>
            <option value=17>Option 4</option>
        </select>
    </article>
</form>
```

Any recommendations on how to retrieve the form?

Answer (score 0):

To submit the complex or recursive model form you could use JavaScript and JSON. by using JS you could extract data from the form and then make ajax request to submit the data to the server side.

Below is the sample code by using you can do that:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var model = buildJSONObjectFromForm(); 
    fetch('/Launch/Home/RetrieveSelection', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'RequestVerificationToken' : document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value  
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(model),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Handle the response data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle errors
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // Include this if you're using ASP.NET's anti-forgery token
public ActionResult RetrieveSelection([FromBody] TowerMeasureModel model)
{
    // Your code to handle the model saving it to the database

    // Return a JSON response or other required action result
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Data received" });
}
```